# How to group elements of a list?

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I have a list of lists. Each list contains three elements, call them `[number, letter, time]`. It looks like this:

```
my_list = [[0, 'a', '0:00'],
           [1, 'a', '1:00'],
           [2, 'b', '2:00'],
           [3, 'c', '3:00'],
           [4, 'b', '4:00'],
           [5, 'a', '5:00'],
           [6, 'd', '6:00'],
           [7, 'c', '7:00'],
           [8, 'b', '8:00'],
           [9, 'e', '9:00']]
```

I want to format this list such that `element[1]`, the `letter` of each nested list becomes `element[0]` of a new nested list, with the occurrences of `number` and `time` as `element[1]` and `element[2]`.

The output I want should look like this

```
my list = [['a', [0, 1, 5], ['0:00', '1:00', '5:00']],
           ['b', [2, 4, 8], ['2:00', '4:00', '8:00']],
           ['c', [3, 7], ['3:00', '7:00']],
           ['d', [6], ['6:00']],
           ['e', [9], ['9:00']]]
```

So far I have used `collections.Counter()` to get the frequency of `letter`

```
>>> letter_count = Counter([element[1] for element in my_list])
>>> letter_count
Counter({'a': 3, 'b': 3, 'c': 2, 'd': 1, 'e': 1})
```

I believe I can use a list comprehension to get the rest of the way, using `letter_count.keys()` and a conditional, but I'm stuck. Any suggestions?

Also, any suggestions on a better, more descriptive title (for posterity's sake) are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a quick n' dirty approach (same efficiency as current other answers, but more code)

```
my_list = [[0, 'a', '0:00'],
           [1, 'a', '1:00'],
           [2, 'b', '2:00'],
           [3, 'c', '3:00'],
           [4, 'b', '4:00'],
           [5, 'a', '5:00'],
           [6, 'd', '6:00'],
           [7, 'c', '7:00'],
           [8, 'b', '8:00'],
           [9, 'e', '9:00']]

tmp_dict = {}

for first, second, third in my_list:
    if second not in tmp_dict:
        tmp_dict[second] = [[],[]]

    tmp_dict[second][0].append(first)
    tmp_dict[second][1].append(third)

new_list = []

for key, val in tmp_dict.items():
    new_list.append([key] + val)

print(new_list)
```

Comment: I like this approach, it uses only tools I already know about. Appreciate it!

Comment: Glad it helped. Please mark is as accepted if you think it's the most intuitive.

Answer (score 4):

```
out = {}
for a, b, c in my_list:
    out.setdefault(b, []).append((a, c))

out = [[k, [i for i, _ in v], [i for _, i in v]]  for k, v in out.items()]

print(out)
```

Prints:

```
[['a', [0, 1, 5], ['0:00', '1:00', '5:00']], 
 ['b', [2, 4, 8], ['2:00', '4:00', '8:00']], 
 ['c', [3, 7], ['3:00', '7:00']], 
 ['d', [6], ['6:00']], 
 ['e', [9], ['9:00']]]
```

Comment: Welp that was quick

Comment: Gonna take me a minute to wrap my head around that lol. Thank you!

Any suggestions on the title?

Comment: @McQuestion I would say `How to group elements of a list?`

Answer (score 2):

Another approach is to use `itertools.groupby`

```
import itertools

new_list = []
my_list = sorted(my_list, key=lambda row: row[1])
for name, groups in itertools.groupby(my_list, key=lambda row: row[1]):
    groups = list(zip(*groups))
    
    grouped_item = [name, groups[0], groups[2]]
    new_list.append(grouped_item)
    
print(new_list)
[['a', (0, 1, 5), ('0:00', '1:00', '5:00')],
 ['b', (2, 4, 8), ('2:00', '4:00', '8:00')],
 ['c', (3, 7), ('3:00', '7:00')],
 ['d', (6,), ('6:00',)],
 ['e', (9,), ('9:00',)]]
```